# Media queries for mobile - widths incorrect

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile, responsive-design, mobile-safari

I've been working on a responsive site. I have been using Chrome developer tools to override the screen size to 320px and using media queries to change the CSS. This is the media query I've used:

```
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 480px) {
```

On my browser this works correctly and I get this (set the viewport as 320 x 480px):

[image]

However when viewing it on an iPhone 5 this is the result, it's the same as the full width version][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDcPm.jpg):

[image]

You can view the full media query CSS [here](http://www.haselden.co.uk/rttest/css/media.css)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```

In your `<head>` tags.

It means your website will scale to the devices width rather than the default width.